# Is there a way to detect a specific persons voice in python with speech recognition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, voice

I am adding on to a virtual desktop assistant that I have made and I want to make it so if my voice is detected it will greet me but if somebody else talks to it, it won't talk or will greet them. Does anybody have any idea on how I should approach this?

Comment: I'm curious, what did you use to build your desktop assistant? And you could build a quick deep classifier for that.

Comment: You asked what I used to build my assistant, do you mean what libraries or what ide or something else? Sorry I got a bit confused.

Comment: what libraries / learners

Comment: I used 21 libraries. datetime, date from datetime, pyowm, requests, speech_recognition, wikipedia, random, pyttsx3, wolframalpha, psutil, platform, threading, image grab from pil, os, ctypes, wmi, webbrowser, beautifulsoup, urllib.request, serial, and mixer from pygame. Thats all I imported, hope that answers your question.

Comment: thanks, that does answer my question!